# How to continue with an If statement

Tags: if-statement, statements

Okay so for this code, I ask for someones favorite number, then ask them to pick a letter. The letter is assigned to a variable. For example, if the letter they choose is A (or lowercase A), add two to the original number, if the letter is m, the number gets multiplied by two, and if the letter is S, the number has 2 subtracted from it. However, i want to keep the loop going, and after one letter is applied, say A, and the number has 2 added on to it, i want that total to go through another loop. The problem is, I don't know how to get it to return the loop so that it may continue asking for the letters so it can continue adding, subtracting or multiplying.

For example, Favorite number is 4, i choose letter A and have 2 added on to A and the variable that held the number 4 now holds the number 6. Now it asks again, what letter should i choose, and i choose A again, and the variable is now 8, and i choose m and it multiplies by 2 to get 16 and so forth until a character besides A, S or M is chosen.

This is a question from an old java test i saw online. It didn't have the finished result, and i'm struggling trying to find an answer to this. I am a beginner java programmer trying to learn from Youtube and i don't get complete explanations most of the time so bear with any mistakes in the code :/

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class question2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      int Total;          
      char Letter;

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Whats your favorite number");
      Total = keyboard.nextInt();   

      System.out.println("Pick a letter from the following: A, S, M");
      Letter = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

      while (Letter == 'A'|| Letter == 'a'|| Letter == 's'|| Letter == 'S'|| 
      Letter == 'm'|| Letter == 'M')
        {
        if(Letter == 'a'|| Letter == 'A')
          {
           Total = Total + 2;
           System.out.println("2 added to your number is "+Total+".");
           return;
          }   

        if(Letter == 's'|| Letter == 'S')
          {
           Total = Total - 2;
           System.out.println("2 subtracted from your number is 
           "+Total+".");
           return;
          }
        if(Letter == 'm'|| Letter == 'M')
          {
           Total = Total - 2;
           System.out.println("2 subtracted from your number is 
           "+Total+".");
           return;
          } 
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return` in all statements and at the end of the loop, place this again:
`System.out.println("Pick a letter from the following: A, S, M");
Letter = keyboard.next().charAt(0);`

Comment: This works to an extent; It does keep the loop going, but does not change the variable of the number each time the letter is applied to it. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true){

      System.out.println("Whats your favorite number");
      Total = keyboard.nextInt();   

      System.out.println("Pick a letter from the following: A, S, M");
      Letter = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

      if...
      if...
      if...
}
```

And remove returns from your if statements. On the side note, start the variable names with small letters.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code to use a do while loop:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Pick a letter from the following: A, S, M");
    String input = keyboard.next().toUpperCase();

    if (input.equals("S") || input.equals("M")) {
        Total = Total - 2;
        System.out.println("2 subtracted from your number is " + Total + ".");
    }
    else if (input.equals("A")) {
        Total = Total + 2;
        System.out.println("2 added to your number is " + Total + ".");
    }
} while(input.equals("S") || input.equals("M") || input.equals("A"));
```

The above loop will spin so long as the user inputs `A`, `M`, or `S`, case insensitive.

I also changed your scanner logic to capture an entire string, rather than a single character.  It is much easier to deal with inputs in a case insensitive manner using a string versus a character.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        long favNumber = 4;
        boolean goOn = true;
        do {
            char ch = reader.next().charAt(0);
            switch (ch) {
                case 'A':
                case 'a':
                    favNumber += 2;
                    break;
                case 'S':
                case 's':
                    favNumber -= 2;
                    break;
                case 'M':
                case 'm':
                    favNumber *= 2;
                    break;
                default:
                    goOn = false;
                    break;
            }
        } while (goOn);
        System.out.println(favNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is probably too advanced for me. I am not saying this is intermediate or anything, I just learned a certain way from pieces of a text book and youtube videos and as of now, don't know some of the stuff you wrote in here. I am trying to do the code with as much knowledge as I know right now, and am basically trying to find an answer on this forum that I completely understand. I'll keep this code so that I may one day, when I researched even more, come back to it to see if i understand everything here completely. Thank you.

Comment: @Jeff: just as a tip for your future use, If you have lots of conditions on primitive types (e.g. numbers or letters) use "switch" instead of "if".

Answer (score 0):

Doing bare minimum change to your code, here is how it stands.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class question2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       int Total;          
       char Letter;

       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Whats your favorite number");
       Total = keyboard.nextInt();   

       System.out.println("Pick a letter from the following: A, S, M");
       Letter = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

       while (Letter == 'A'|| Letter == 'a'|| Letter == 's'|| Letter == 'S'|| 
  Letter == 'm'|| Letter == 'M')
        {
        if(Letter == 'a'|| Letter == 'A')
          {
           Total = Total + 2;
           System.out.println("2 added to your number is "+Total+".");
          }   

        if(Letter == 's'|| Letter == 'S')
          {
           Total = Total - 2;
           System.out.println("2 subtracted from your number is 
       "+Total+".");
          }
        if(Letter == 'm'|| Letter == 'M')
          {
           Total = Total - 2;
           System.out.println("2 subtracted from your number is 
       "+Total+".");
          } 
        Letter = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
       }
     return;
     }
  }
```

Here, we are not ending the function (`return`) as soon as one operation is done, instead, we ask another letter from user and go back to the condition of checking whether the letter is a/m/s and hence **repeating the process untill user enters a different letter**.

Of course other answers have more **well-documented, clean** and **standardized** code, so i thought of posting the code with *minimal* changes.

But please go through the other answers for better programming practices.

Comment: Thank you. This works great and it was only a bit of tweaking. As I said I am a beginner, so some of the answers here are going a bit over my head (not saying they don't work as they definitely do even better and more efficient than mines) but this one is pretty much spot on and easy to understand where I went wrong. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome Jeff! It served the purpose well.  :-)